# JavaScript String Manipulation

Tags: javascript, string

I'm using Javascript to grab a variable passed through the URL:

```
function get_url_parameter( param ){
  param = param.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var r1 = "[\\?&]"+param+"=([^&#]*)";
  var r2 = new RegExp( r1 );
  var r3 = r2.exec( window.location.href );
  if( r3 == null )
   return "";
  else
    return r3[1];
 }
```

Once I have the parameter required

```
var highlightsearch = get_url_parameter('search');
```

I want to be able to delete all of the string after the ">".

e.g

The result currently looks like this:

```
highlightsearch = "Approved%20XXXXX%20XXXXX>YYYY%20YYYYYYY%20YYYY%20-%20YYYY%20YYYY";
```

After my string manipulation I want it to hopefully look like

```
highlightsearch = "Approved%20XXXXX%20XXXXX";
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Shameless plug, but your URL param function isn't very efficient, it doesn't work with encoded params or decode the result.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery/2880929#2880929 for a more robust solution.

Comment: Thanks Andy, learning a lot this evening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression to match ">" and everything after it: `>.*`

```
highlightsearch = highlightsearch.replace(/>.*/, '')
```

Comment: Thanks folks. Working on it now.

Answer (score 2):

The following will get you everything before the ">":

```
var highlightsearch = get_url_parameter('search');

// highlightsearch = "1234>asdf"

highlightsearch = highlightsearch.slice(0, highlightsearch.indexOf(">"));

// highlightsearch = "1234"
```